# Did the humans hear what Arishem said at the end of Eternals?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, eternals-2021

At the end of Eternals (2021)...

> Arishem pops up on Earth and tells the remaining Eternals that he will return to judge whether humankind should be spared. Afterwards, the humans in London are stumbling around quite shocked. Were they shocked only by the appearance of a Celestial in the sky, or because they heard/sensed/knew what Arishem just said?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### There are a few things which imply that the people on Earth *didn't* hear what Arishem said.

Firstly, while Arishem looks pretty close to the Earth in some shots, there's a shot where we see Sersi being pulled away from Earth, and it looks like she's travelling quite a long distance from it. Not quite as far as the Moon's orbit, but certainly tens of thousands of miles beyond the Earth's atmosphere.

[image]

Assuming that sound doesn't travel in space in the MCU, it follows that Arishem probably wasn't communicating with the Eternals via audible speech. A more logical interpretation would be that he was communicating using telepathy, or some other method.

Even if we theorise that physics were being ignored here, and that he *was* communicating via audible speech, his voice didn't seem that loud from the perspective of Sersi, Kingo, and Phastos, who were relatively close to him at the time. It therefore seems unlikely that his voice could be heard by humans tens of thousands of miles away on the Earth's surface.

Secondly, since Arishem is a cosmic being of incredible power, he likely could be heard by humans on Earth from that distance, if he wished to be. However, his message seemed to be directed squarely at the Eternals, not the human race. This is suggested by what he said, specifically, but also, if he wanted his message to be heard by Eternals and humans alike, why would he pull the Eternals so far away from Earth before he began speaking?

> ARISHEM: You have chosen to sacrifice a Celestial for the people of this planet. I will spare them, but your memories will show if they are worthy to live. And I will return for judgment.
>
> <sub>[*Eternals (2021)* - transcript](https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/movies/eternals-2021-transcript/)</sub>

As a final point, when the film cuts back to the Earth's surface, a woman can just about be heard saying *"Did you see that?"*. It doesn't seem likely that someone would only ask if others *saw* Arishem, if he wasn't just visible in the sky, but if his words were *heard* on Earth as well. Admittedly, you have to strain a bit to hear this line, as it's only spoken by a nameless bystander in the background, but it is included in the transcript.

> WOMAN 2: Did you see that?
>
> <sub>*Eternals (2021)* - transcript</sub>

Comment: Thanks. The last point (the extra's line) is the most convincing to me. The mechanics of Arishem's communication is speculative and I was looking for something canon. And it's obvious that the message is intended for the Eternals, but the intentions don't really answer whether anyone else can "overhear" it to some degree (or psychically sense it or however it works).

Comment: I speculated in terms of proposing what the alternative mode of communication (other than audible speech) might've been, but that was incidental to the underlying point. That being that Arishem was speaking in the vacuum of space, tens of thousands of miles away from the Earth, meaning that the sound of his voice (if it _was_ simply audible speech) couldn't possibly have carried all the way to the Earth's surface, unless sound travels in space in the MCU.